Python Pandas multi-indexing across column levels using .loc
I am still new to python and pandas and want to know if there's a better way to go about the indexing problem I'm having. Since I've seen people doing pretty slick things on this site, beyond what I can generally glean from the docs, I thought I would ask -- especially since I'm still learning.
I have a DataFrame that has multiple column levels, with level 0 being "meta" and "rna" and level 1 being "subject_id", "disease", "time", and "status" under "meta" and many thousands of EnsemblGeneID's under "rna." To me, if I wanted a specific subset of "meta" columns and all of my "rna" columns, I would just pass a list of tuples to df.loc[]:
selected_columns = df.loc[:, [("meta", "subject_id"), ("meta", "status"), ("rna",:)]]
But this does not work and, according to the documentation, it appears that there's nothing as elegant as this. Does anyone know of a sleek way to perform this action?
I've tried various methods of passing things to df.loc[] to experiment, but most errored out with various keyerrors, slicing errors, etc. and what I could get to work was not nearly as elegant to what might be possible. Still trying to figure out if I can use indexers but that seems overly complicated compared to single leveled dfs.
The closest thing I've found that worked was suggested by ChatGPT:
selected_columns = df.loc[:, [('meta', 'subject_id'), ('meta', 'status')] + [('rna', col) for col in df['rna'].columns]]
Maybe this is as slick as it gets, but this isn't as intuitive as the way single level DataFrames work and I've seen some wizardry on here before so wanted to give asking here a shot. Also, maybe some experienced pythoners can tell me I'm totally wrong for trying to navigate DataFrames like this and that I should be doing something else.
Edit:
So far, I've settled on making selected_columns = pd.IndexSlice[ . . . ]'s of my desired columns, if I need complicated subsets of either "meta" or "rna" columns, which is similar to an answer given below and ChatGPT's. Seems like pandas needs the exact tuple columns indexing to be defined in an "at compile time" sort of manner. Making index slices is not ideal but so far it seems to work okay.
As for anyone in the future who wishes to help, he's a bigger picture view of what I am trying to accomplish with this example table (can't format it with multi-tiered headers):
| meta-------------------------------------------| rna



subject_id
time
sample
gene1
gene2
. . .
gene1000




0xA
00
1
0.001
0.002
. . .
0.004


0xB
04
2
0.002
0.003
. . .
0.005


. . .
. . .
. . .
. . .
. . .
. . .
. . .


0xFF
74
100
0.100
0.101
. . .
0.102



I'd like to easily mix and match columns while being able to reference large chunks of columns. For instance, make a new df, df_new from the subject_id and time columns, and include genes 300-400 or genes 0 to 400 with something that looks like:
df_new = df.loc[:, [("meta", "subject_id"), ("meta", "time"), ("rna", :"gene401")]]
It's looking like there's no easy way to do something like this, other than what's been posted as an answer but if anyone has suggestions, I'd love to hear them.
example excel table since I can't do multi-tiered headers on stack overflow

Why don't you just do selected_columns = df.drop(columns=[("meta", "disease"), ("meta", "time")])?

Kindly provide sample input dataframe with expected output dataframe

So there are 2 issues with this line:
selected_columns = df.loc[:, [("meta", "subject_id"), ("meta", "status"), ("rna",:)]]

First pandas does not recognize df.loc [:, ("rna", :)]. The right syntax would be df.loc [:,"rna"]. The second issue comes from the dimensions/level of indexing : df.loc [:, ("rna", :)] would return a dataframe and that's logical given you would have multiple columns while with df.loc [:, ("meta", "subject_id")] we have a serie given we 'fully index' the column (we specify which level 0 and wich level 1 we are interested in). So even if the syntax is right we would be mixing different level of indexing in the loc argument.
In order to keep the code readable I would suggest this (which is in fact what ChatGPT proposed !):
selected_columns_indexes = [("meta", "subject_id"), ("meta", "status")] + [("rna", sub_rna) for sub_rna in df.loc[:, "rna"].columns]
selected_columns = df.loc[:,selected_columns_indexes]

